# Default color for Filling in Mathematica 9

Tags: color

The default color scheme for plots in my *Mathematica* version is `ColorData[1]`. What about for the `Filling` option?

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's the same, but with `Opacity[0.2]`.

(Also, since Mathematica 10 it's `ColorData[97]` instead of `ColorData[1]`.)

Comment: How do you find out the precise default value used for `Opacity` in `Filling`?

Comment: @JulesLamers You can examine the `InputForm` of the `Plot` output and look for `Opacity` directives in it.  `Plot[1, {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 2, Filling -> Axis] // InputForm`

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version
```

> "9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)"

```
max = 40;

funcs = #*x & /@ Range[max];

plt = Plot[funcs, {x, 0, 1},
   PlotStyle -> Black,
   Filling -> (Partition[Range[max], 2, 1] /.
      {a_, b_} :> a -> {b})];
```

The filling colors between the plots are expressed in "HSB", i.e., Hue[{hue, saturation, brightness}]

```
clr = Cases[plt, {x_Opacity, y_Hue} :> {x, y}, Infinity];
```

The hue values are

```
data = clr[[All, 2, 1]];
```

These align with

```
hue[n_] := Mod[.67 + (Sqrt[5] - 2) (n - 1), 1]

Plot[hue[n], {n, 0, max},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[Thread[{Range[max - 1], data}]]},
 AxesLabel -> {"n", "hue"}]
```

[image]

The first 15 values of hue correspond to the colors of ColorData[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZPvH.png) converted from "RGB" to "HSB"

```
List @@@ (ColorConvert[#, "RGB" -> "HSB"] & /@ ColorData[1, "ColorList"]) -
   List @@@ (Hue[hue[#], 0.6, 0.6] & /@ Range[15]) // Chop // Union
```

{{0, 0, 0}}