# What is the default Color Gradient used by ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, color

What ColorFunction does ContourPlot use by default --- that is, what does "Automatic" mean as the value for that option?  The "Density and Contour Plots" tutorial says:

> By default, the color ranges from black
>   to white through intermediate shades of
>   blue as the value of the function increases.

And the default gradient does have blue at the dark end; but it goes through something like orange on the way toward white.

Surprisingly, the default does not seem to be among the 51 gradients listed by ColorData["Gradients"].

Comment: The color scheme is something like `"M10DefaultDensityGradient"`

Comment: With b3m2a1's hint, I found that my question is answered in some detail in:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162883/whats-the-default-colormap-or-color-scheme-used-in-mathematica?rq=1

Comment: to find additional gradient color schemes that are not listed in `ColorData["Gradients"]` you can use `ColorData["*radient*"]`;e.g., `Grid[Partition[
  Labeled[ColorData[#, "Image"], #, Top] & /@ 
   Sort[ColorData["*radient*"]], 4]]`