# Can the default marker shapes for ListPlot be accessed the same way the default color scheme can?

Tags: plotting, default

One of the fun tricks known to Mathematica users is that [the default colors for Mathematica plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162890/27813) (as of v12) can be accessed by the `ColorData[97]` color scheme.  So `ColorData[97][1]` is a light blue, `ColorData[97][2]` is an orange-yellow, etc.  I have found this immensely useful when creating separate plots and then combining them into a single graphic.

`ListPlot` uses this same color scheme but also has a set of different shapes it uses for each data series, as seen below:

[image]

Is there a function similar to `ColorData[97]` that can be called to yield a filled circle given an argument of `1`, a filled square given an argument of `2`, a filled diamond given an argument of `3`, and so forth?

Comment: Have you seen ``System`Private`$PlotMarkers`` already?

Comment: Similarly, to get the ``Graphics`` version: ``Charting`CommonDump`GraphicsPlotMarkers[]``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize comments by Domen and me: `` Graphics`PlotMarkers[] `` (which is aliased by `` System`Private`$PlotMarkers ``) gives glyph versions of the default markers, while `` Charting`CommonDump`GraphicsPlotMarkers[] `` gives the `Graphics[]` version of the default markers.

In particular, consider the following:

```
rr = RandomReal[1, 7];
ListPlot[Outer[Plus, Range[0, 9], rr], PlotMarkers -> Automatic] === 
ListPlot[Outer[Plus, Range[0, 9], rr],
         PlotMarkers -> Charting`CommonDump`GraphicsPlotMarkers[]]
   True
```

Comment: I always feel vaguely sinful accessing one of those functions involving a left apostrophe.  (What are those *called*, anyhow?)

Comment: We just refer to them as *undocumented*, for convenience. ;)