# How to get the color from a plot?

Tags: plotting, color

I need to get the color from cells of the plot built by `ArrayPlot[]` or `MatrixPlot[]` for later use in, e.g.,  `Style[]` or other functions

Comment: I think the most robust solution would be to generate the list of colors yourself, rather than trying to extract it from the output of those functions. To this end, take a look at [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) and [`ColorFunctionScaling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html) to understand how the colors are generated from the color function, and see e.g. [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162883/) for the default color function used by Mathematica.

Comment: OK, I'll try to learn these issues in more details for this task

Comment: I agree with the first comment especially that the colors might change each time the matrix is changed . For one particular matrix, a possibility (with some issues) might be to use something like `MatrixPlot[Array[#1 + #2 &, {4, 4}]] // DominantColors` however it adds white among the colors due to the background. The white color might or might not be in the original plot. Also you might need to specify options at times and it might not work as you wish at times.

Answer (score 2):

You could extract them from the plot

```
plot = ArrayPlot[{{1, 0, 0, 0.3}, {1, 1, 0, 0.3},
    {1, 0, 1, 0.7}}, ColorRules -> {1 -> Pink, 0 -> Yellow}];

colours = RGBColor @@@ Union[Catenate[plot[[1, 1]]]]
```