# Using the classic contour plot theme

Tags: plot-themes

I am writing a manuscript and all my plots were made in a slightly older version of Mathematica (version 12). The old contour plots had this blue to gold to white coloring scheme (see attached). When I updated Mathematica, they are now a sunset theme (see attached). Is there a way to use the old version of the contour theme?  Thanks in Advance.

**Classic:**

[image]

**New Default, Sunset:**

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162883/whats-the-default-colormap-or-color-scheme-used-in-mathematica) work with your new version?

Comment: @Syed That fixed it perfectly. Thank you